# Semicolons at beginning of the line, delims and FOR cycle

Tags: batch-file

I cannot figure out how to correctly identify an empty/undefined variable having two semicolon one after one other or the line that starts with it.

This is the cycle:

`for /F "delims=; tokens=1-7" %%m IN (testlist.txt) DO echo FUNCGROUP=%%r a=%%m b=%%n c=%%o d=%%p e=%%q f=%%s`

I also tried adding `"eol=;"` and `"......eol="` without success.

This is content of the first line of the file testlist.txt:

```
;xxxxxx;Active;;FALSE;con ter - dong;HWID000001;Item;sites/coll-
```

The result I need is, for the first cycle:

> ```
> a=
> b=xxxxxx
> c=Active
> d=
> e=FALSE
> f=con ter - dong
> g=HWID000001
> ```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, you need to put a "NULL value" for empty fields in the lines of the file.
As there is no direct string substitution utilities with batch, you have to make substitutions beforehand to create "empty" fields. I suggest you to use a "NULL" character for empty fields like unbreakable space (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>).

In your case, this gives :

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "eol= tokens=*" %%l in (file.txt) DO (
  SET "LINE=%%l"
  SET "LINE=###!LINE:;;=; ;!###"
  SET "LINE=!LINE:###;= ;!"
  SET "LINE=!LINE:;###=; !"
  SET "LINE=!LINE:###=!"
  for /F "delims=; tokens=1-7" %%m in ("!LINE!") DO (
     SET "RES=FUNCGROUP=%%r a=%%m b=%%n c=%%o d=%%p e=%%q f=%%s"
     echo !RES: =!
  )
)
```

Note that the `SET "LINE=###!LINE:;;=; ;!###"`, `SET "LINE=!LINE:###;= ;!"` and the `SET "LINE=!LINE:;###=; !"` sections use the unbreakable space (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>) and replace beginning ";" with "<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>;", the ending ";" with ";<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>" and any following ";;" with ";<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>;". The for loop parses then correctly the line, and next you just have to remove the unbreakable space to get "empty" variables.

**EDIT:** As brightly suggested by @jeb in the comments, you can also use quotes to handle empty fields. Each for loop variables can be then directly and simply unquoted.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "eol= tokens=*" %%l in (file.txt) DO (
  SET "LINE=%%l"
  SET "LINE=###^"!LINE:;=^";^"!^"###"
  SET "LINE=!LINE:###^";=^"^";!"
  SET "LINE=!LINE:;^"###=;^"^"!"
  SET "LINE=!LINE:###=!"
  for /F "delims=; tokens=1-7" %%m in ("!LINE!") DO (
     echo FUNCGROUP=%%~r a=%%~m b=%%~n c=%%~o d=%%~p e=%%~q f=%%~s
  )
)
```

Comment: You could replace `;` with `";"` instead and enclose the complete line into quotes, then you get `"";"Active";"";"FALSE";"dong";"HWID000001";"Item";"sites"`. Then all tokens can be used with `%%~a`

Comment: @jeb Quote and dequote, good idea. The content provided with the question doesn't seems to potentially include quotes in the fields, i'll edit the answer to add your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have not provided sufficient information for what you intend to do with your empty field, so this is only a demonstration to provide you with output similar to that which you've indicated in your question:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ("(Set Field[) 2>NUL") Do Set "%%G="
Set "i=0"
For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("testlist.txt") Do Call :GetFields "%%G"
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:GetFields
Set "Record=%~1"
Set /A i += 1
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Index=1"
Set "Field[!Index!]=%Record:;=" & Set /A Index +=1 & Set "Field[!Index!]=%"
Echo(&Echo Record !i!
For /L %%G In (1,1,!Index!) Do If Not Defined Field[%%G] (Echo Field[%%G]=) Else Set Field[%%G]
Exit /B
```